# Query Fine Tuning

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to sql and would like to ask for your assistance regarding this query. Is there another way to rewrite this?

```
 Select *
 From emp
 Where emp_no IN (
     Select emp_no
     From dept_emp
     Where dept_no = 'd002'
     );
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select * 
from emp
where exists(
    select 1 from dept_emp where dept_emp.emp_no = emp.emp_no and dept_no = 'd002'
)
```

also maybe `inner join` work:

```
select emp.*
from emp
join dept_emp
on dept_emp.emp_no = emp.emp_no
and dept_no = 'd002'
```

Comment: why `not exists`?

Comment: no probs. I had to double check my answer because of yours.. :p

Comment: Can you kindly explain how the two works so I would know why its better than my previous query

Comment: Your query works as you know and it's more apparent. My first query do the thing that querys emps which exists in `dept_emp` and `dept_no = 'd002'`, my second query use `inner join` which will fetch emp exists in both table, and then filter these emps with `dept_no = 'd002'`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an inner join

```
select * 
from emp
inner join (
    Select emp_no
     From dept_emp
     Where dept_no = 'd002'

) t on emp_no.id = t.emp_no
```

or  without subselect

```
select * 
from emp
inner join dept_emp on emp_no.id = dept_emp.emp_no 
   and dept_emp.dept_no = 'd002'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join like this:

`select * from emp e, dept_emp d where e.emp_no = d.emp_no and d.dept_no = 'd002'`

Answer (score 0):

```
 - If have the relation between two tables best-way you can used join. other wise you can used inner query (sub select) 
 - When you used join in RDBMS it will faster that inner query.
 - join must be indexed based like: primary key and foreign key. Other wise executing cost will be high. non-index query time consumed maximum.
```